# I don't know what is wrong with my pc. Kernel error 41 while gaming with old and new PSU

Tags: crash, gaming

I've been having some issues with my Pc and after searching the web have not been able to fix it.

PC SPEC:

```
ASUS Z170 Pro gaming
i7 6700 CPU
cooler is a Corsair H100i v2
GPU Geforce GTX 1080 ti
PSU Corsair HX850i
ram: HyperX Fury (2x, 16GB, DDR4-2133, DIMM 288)
```

My problem:

PC shuts down while playing graphic-intensive games. At first Asus, surge protection said it restarted the pc, but after a while, that message disappeared, and now it just crashes.
I can surf the web watch youtube ect without issues all day, it really only happens while gaming.

The event manager says:

> The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
>
> Keywords: 0x8000400000000002
> Guid: {331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}

What I already did:
Change the PSU for a brand new one, as well as the cables.
checked all the connections, and plug-in/out all components.
Ran Memtest, no errors
Ran OCCT test, no errors.
Rest windows
reinstalled all drivers
Flashed bios

I have literally NO idea what is wrong with my PC and it is slowly making me insane, any pointers are welcome!
enter image description here

Comment: You could verify the temperature while gaming, meaning bad ventilation. Using [Prime95](https://www.mersenne.org/download/) might be easier.

Comment: Just for testing, nvidia control panel now allows for a framerate cap. Have you tried setting a global cap to e.g. 60fps to see if this resolves it? Some (older) games can run into the 1000s FPS during startup and menus which can trigger shutdowns. Asus surge protect is purportedly unreliable and over protective.

Comment: hey guys, thanks for the quick replies, temps while gaming seemed ok, but I'll take a look again.
for FPS: I did not try, but seeing as I've had crashes in rainbow six siege, civ6, hades... not sure about that.

Comment: Here are my temps in game:https://snipboard.io/Lb6m3w.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I've done some tests on my side using rainbow six siege. after lowering the resolution down from 4K to  2xxx x 19xx, I managed to run it for several hours without hiccups. So it seems that whenever I'm pushing my GPU too much my PC restarts (kernel 41).